# Can a bobble be bobbled?

Tags: the-peace-war

I've started rereading Vernor Vinge's [*Peace War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?703) stories and wondered whether his "bobble"-type stasis fields could enclose another bobble field.  In Niven's [*Known Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?653) universe we know the answer:  one stasis field can't operate inside another, and you can use this fact to deactivate stasis fields.  But I don't remember if this matter was ever covered in the *Peace War* books.  There is something called a "Wachendon suppressor field" mentioned that prevents new bobble fields from being created, but that doesn't answer the question.

**Can one bobble field enclose another?**

Comment: I'm about 96% certain that bobbles cannot be created around other bobbles and it is in fact used as a defense against bobbling - having smaller bobbles in strategic areas that make it difficult to encompass a large area.  I'll try to dig up in-text evidence.

Comment: I don't have a copy handy, but I'm pretty sure that yes, you can bobble a bobble. If not, you could immunize from bobbling just by carrying a small bobble. (Hah, ninja'd by @starpilotsix, who recalls the opposite.)

Comment: Fascinating.  Both possibilities seem equally plausible.

Comment: Can you [bobble a bobbled bobble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu6Ot.png)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At least in [*The Peace War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1408), the answer seems to be no:

> "Everything seems consistent. There are a lot of things that were barred under your old theory, that are still impossible: It's still impossible to burst a bobble before its time. It's impossible to generate a bobble around an existing one. On the other hand - in theory at least - it should be possible to balk an enemy bobbler."
>
> "Hmm..." Simply carrying a small bobble was a kind of defense against bobble attack - a very risky defense, once noticed: It would force the attacker to project smaller bobbles, or off-center ones, trying to find a volume that wasn't 'banned.' A device that could prevent bobbles from being formed nearby would be a tremendous improvement, and Naismith had guessed the new theory might allow such, but...

Many bobbling strategies depend on this property.  For example, defensively self-bobbling yourself for long or short periods of time has been occasionally useful.  If you could bobble a bobble, then you could subvert those plans... turn a two hour or for that matter a thousand year bobble into a million-year-bobble by enclosing it in another bobble of longer duration.

Of course, the original bobble theory held that time still passed within bobbles and that they would not decay, and those proved to be wrong so it's theoretically possible that one can find a way to bobble a bobble, but at least in the initially developed technique, it's considered impossible.